# GARCH QML in matlab

Tags: matlab, arima

I would like to calculate parameters for a GARCH using QML. I was wondering if the ARIMA toolbox from Matlab gives us the QML errors?

Greetings

Comment: Unfortunately, GARCH estimation with Matlab is performed through maximum-likelihood. Hence you have to implement your own GARCH model if you want to use QMLE.